# Netbeans incorrectly flagging a final variable as already assigned

Tags: java, netbeans

I have some code that is, as far as this problem is concerned, equivalent to

```
final int n;
try {
    n = someFunctionThatThrowsMyException();
} catch (MyException e){
    n = 4;
}
```

But NetBeans issues an error "variable n might already have been assigned" in the catch block.

Is that *really* the case? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You need to do something like this instead:

```
final int n;
int temp;
try {
    temp = someFunctionThatThrowsMyException();
} catch (MyException e){
    temp = 4;
}
n = temp;
```

Comment: @The New Idiot: a fat finger ;-) See edit.

Comment: It's all explained in the link that Nanne posted.